# Editing individual records

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am a jquery beginner. We are building a site and I would appreciate if you could help me with these issues. We are using PHP-MySQL

There are 2 issues:

1) I have a set of labels, which show the basic information about a user like phone number, address etc. I have provided an EDIT button. When it is clicked, I am hiding the labels div and am showing a div with input fields. How do I fill these input fields with the label contents so that the user can directly edit them ? There are 3 divs in 1 parent div with 3 labels in each div.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="span12">
     <div class="control-group">
        <div class="span2">
            <label class="help">Date of Birth</label>
            <label id="dob" class="control-label">12-12-1202</label>
        </div>
        <div class="span2">
            <label class="help">Phone Number</label>
            <label id="phone" class="control-label">2125558246</label>
        </div>
        <div class="span2">
            <label class="help">Skype ID</label>
            <label id="skypeid" class="control-label">honululu_785</label>
        </div>
        <div class="span2">
            <label class="help">E-Mail</label>
            <label id="email" class="control-label">red_dragon@panda.com</label>
        </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

2) There is section called EDUCATIONAL INFORMATION wherein the user will have multiple records of his/her education details. The details include Institute name, Duration, Degree name and a certificate. So there will be 2+ records. Each record will have an EDIT button. Again, here the labels field will be hidden and a div with input fields will be shown, which needs to be pre-filled with those label values. How do I capture which EDIT button was clicked so that the corresponding labels could be shown in the input fields ?

Thanking in advance for any help...

Comment: 1. Are you hiding the `<label>` or `<div class="span2">`? Do you mean user can directly edit a label without clicking edit icon?

Comment: try this for 1) `var dobValue = $( "#dob" ).val();` after that you must set this value to the inputfield `$( "#iputid").val(dobValue)`

Answer (score 1):

I have done this same thing with an online store that I created using PHP. PHP is probably your easiest option, I simply would query the database and store the information I need in some variables on the pages load, then I would insert PHP code into the actual HTML to echo out the desired values. I am not able to give my example code from my site at the moment but I will update the answer with it later,

But the PHP in the HTML would look something like this:

`<input type="text" name="fieldName" value="<?PHP echo $variableName; ?>">`

Comment: This is the same way I am using for an internal backend interface I developed, too. Simply echo the value for that field into the hidden `<input>` element.

Answer (score 0):

1. For problem 1

`<input type="text" name="input_dob" value="<?php echo $dob;?>">`

1. For problem 2

`<?php for($i;$i<count($educations);$i++) { ?>
        <input type="text" name="input_educ_institute[]" value="<?php echo $educations[$i]["institute"];?>">
        ....
    <?php }?>`

Comment: We were actually going for this method.. We are sending back all the data as json from php because the page uses ajax to refresh the divs. Is there any to separate the html from php?

Comment: Posting you code for ajax call will be helpful. You can parse the JSON data from php and create a DOM element using javascript.

Comment: The json data that is received by the ajax call is a multi-dimensional array. How do I generate divs that represent each element for that multi-dimensional array ? Also, the EDIT button of each div should edit just that record.